# Changing SELECT OPTION dropdown data with button click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate dropdown lists through javascript, but I seem to get this code every time I click a button:

> TypeError: objDropDownMenu.options is undefined
>
> objDropDownMenu.options[1].selected = true;

Here is my code:

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
<SELECT class="select diff_data" style="WIDTH: 165px" name=CarPick>
<OPTION value=1>Audi</OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>BMW</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3>Mercedes</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Write" onClick="writeText(this.form)">
</FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var objDropDownMenu = document.getElementsByName("CarPick");



function writeText (form) {
    objDropDownMenu.options[30].selected = true;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Anyu idea why? Thanks!

Comment: And where is `ProcStage` defined?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change it in my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if your code is just an example, but if not, there many unmatching names. Lets fix that:

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
<SELECT class="select diff_data" style="WIDTH: 165px" name="CarPick">
<OPTION value="1">Audi</OPTION>
<OPTION value=2>BMW</OPTION>
<OPTION value=3>Mercedes</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Write" onClick="writeText(this.form)">
</FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var objDropDownMenu = document.getElementsByName("CarPick")[0];   //It is get elementS - all alements with that name are returned



function writeText (form) {
    objDropDownMenu.options[2].selected = true;  //Here I wonder if 30th entry exists, 2 surelly does
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` always returns an `array` of `objects`.

So you have to use:
`objDropDownMenu[0].options[30].selected = true`

A better way to approach this is to set an *ID* for your select and then use `document.getElementById('yourid')` which will always return just one object (since the ID should always be unique in a HTML document).